# Does Blender have a main menu?

Tags: blender, blender-game-engine

1 - Does Blender have a main menu, and if so, how do I make it appear? This is what I'm looking at currently:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd0Zf.jpg

2 - Also, that text panel at the top, that is as large as I can make it. Is there any way to make it taller? Or change the panel layout...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It does have a main menu and you must have hidden it.

There is a small plus sign in the upper right corner of the 3D view. Click on it and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If by main menu, you mean the toolbar, you can access that by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>. The properties panel can be accessed by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>. And the majority of settings are changed in the properties *editor*(the default panel in the lower right hand corner. If there's ever a tool that you want to access, but cant remember it's location, use the search bar(<kbd>SPACE</kbd>).